# Should there be continuity between dual primary windings?

Tags: transformer

Background: I have a stand alone PSU for some audio equipment that keeps blowing its fuse. I suspect the step down transformer is the culprit here, but I just want to confirm that I understand this correctly before binning an expensive component.

The transformer in questions in novotem's 422-5304. A toroidal with dual primary and secondary windings. Everything looks fine on visual inspection, but I found the following after removing the transformer from the PSU.

[image: From the datasheet]

With all leads of the transformer disconnected, I'm reading continuity between Violet and Grey, which (as I understand) are on separate windings completely. Incidentally the main power switch was connected between Violet and Grey before I removed the transformer from the PSU.

My questions is. Am I right in understanding that I should not be measuring continuity between these two wires and that this component should be replaced?

Comment: Yes, it is probably bad. But, I would measure all the other windings to be sure that you are measuring where you think you are. Sometimes the colors aren't that good to start with, sometimes they fade.

Comment: If it was used previously and you only removed the switch, it might be internally set up for either parallel or serial operation still, which means that the windings would still be tied together. measure actual resistances. That could give you a better hint (they might be slightly different at the resolution of your meter)

Comment: Is this being powered from 240VAC?  With the power switch across VIO,GRY that implies that BRN was wired to "hot" and BLU was "neutral", correct?  If so, then yes it's toast.

Comment: @rdtsc yup that's the setup it was wired in. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each winding should be isolated from the others and if you measure the resistance of the windings the primaries should both be very close in value and the secondaries should be very close in value.

If you measure a low resistance between either wire of one primary to either wire of the other then there is a short between the windings.

One thing that might have caused that is the way the power switch was wired. With it between the two primaries each winding would be connected to one side of the power lines, even with the switch off. With the switch off a power line spike would create a high potential between the two windings and the insulation might break down. It should be better to connect the windings together and put the switch between the line hot and one side of the primaries.